# Android sticky Service lifecycle, how to know when to call stopSelf()?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm doing media playback so I have a bound foreground service that returns START_STICKY. Simple question: how do I tell when to stopSelf()? I had a few ideas, but they all seem to be torpedoed by various gotchas...

1. Try and detect when my app is no longer running. The usual technique appears to be via ActvityManager.getRunningTasks() but this is now deprecated. Also as we know Activity onDestroyed() may not be called so it can't be relied upon either.
2. Wait for a while: if the audio hasn't been played for, say, 10 minutes, then kill the service. But this has the problem that the app may still be running and my service does some other things like update the UI to show "Coming Up Next" even when the audio isn't playing.

Which leaves me with a kind of ugly option 3: Never call stopSelf() and just don't update the UI if nothing is bound. But make use of stopForeground() to help the system decide to kill the service.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If your app uses 'bindService()' in its 'onStart()' method and 'unbindService()' in its 'onStop()' method your service class can override 'onUnbind()' so the service can act on the notification that the app has stopped.

See also 
[Service.onUnbind()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onUnbind(android.content.Intent))

If the activity is running but the user has stopped replay then you might want to release the mediaplayer (which does not necessarily mean stopping the service).

AFAIK if some UI element (e.g. a TextView) already has that "Coming up next" information it won't lose it just because the service releases the mediaplayer or calls 'stopSelf()'. And while replay is stopped there will be no new song coming up next.

Maybe you want to write this kind of information to SharedPreferences or to the SQLite database as soon as the activity enters 'onPause()' and retrieve it in 'onCreate()'.

Comment: Application has no onStart or onStop, these are Activity methods and can't help you determine if your app is running due to the nature of the Activity lifecycle. As I said in the question "up next" will change even if the audio isn't playing (it's a streaming talkback radio app). I think my option 3 may actually be the "correct" approach, since really Android has no concept of "application running".